# Автозаполнение полей на нескольких сайтах по заданным атрибутам

Tags: javascript, linux, веб-программирование

Всем привет, подскажите на чем возможно реализовать программу, которая будет по входным данным заполнять нужные мне поля, суть этого автозаполнения в упрощение моей работы по созданию пользователя на 4 ресурсах нашей компании, где по сути вводится одно и тоже, в JS я реализовал это, но приходится запускать скрипт на разных сайтах постоянно заново, так как locate, отменяет последующие инструкции, возможно ли это сделать на руби например, или подскажите как проще.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте копнуть не в автозаполнение полей, а в сам уходящий запрос. Можно проанализировать разметку или, к примеру, в хроме это можно посмотреть в консоли на вкладке Network. Там можно найти страницу и переданные на нее параметры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этом случае Вы просто можете создать скрипт на Ruby или Python, который отошлет HTTP POST запрос на сервер и зарегистрирует тем самым пользователя.

Comment: У меня все данные отправляются не в строке запроса, а в его теле, и я понятия не имею как их подменять, можно пример на руби как заполнить 1 поле, дальше я уже все сделаю, спасибо огромное

Comment: @СергейКрылов, когда данные передаются в теле, это называется POST запрос, а когда в строке GET запрос. Вам надо из Ruby отправить POST, я не сильно в нем разбираюсь, но Вам нужна стандартная функция из net/http, как-то так: https://sites.google.com/site/sitsiliyaror/blogs/klass-net-http-dla-generacii-zaprosov

Answer (score 0):

Например, написать api-метод для каждого из сайтов, который будет принимать данные для создания нового пользователя.

А на одном из сайтов использовать при отправки данных дополнительно еще 3 post запроса, которые будут обращаться к этим api для добавления пользователя